# $rootScope to set active tab not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

would anyone be able to help me on this issue I am having?
I have a NavCtrl for manage my active tag, I was able to change the active tab when click on the menu item, however when I click on the link in the body views, it take me to the page I want to, but the active tag is not change.

```
//controller for nevigation menu
sp.controller('NavCtrl', ['$scope', 'auth', '$window','$rootScope', function ($scope, auth, $window,$rootScope) {
    $scope.LogOut = auth.logOut;
    $scope.isLoggedIn = auth.isLoggedIn;
    $scope.tab = $rootScope.navTav;

    $scope.toTop = function(){
        $window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    };
}]);
```

I try to use the $rootScope to set the navTab, but it's still not working

```
//setting root scope
sp.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.navTav = 1;
})
```

ui-Router

```
.state('qaanswer', {
    url: '/qa/{quesId}',
    views: {
        view50': {
            templateUrl: './qa/qaanswer.html',
            controller: 'QAAnswerCtrl'
        },
        'view60': {
            templateUrl: './shareviews/activityupdates.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        }
    },
    onEnter:['$rootScope',function($rootScope){
        $rootScope.navTav = 5;
    }]
```

Thank you so much for the help

Comment: Can you post the navigation html too. If you are using $rootScope then you do not need to write  $scope.tab = $rootScope.navTav; this line. you can simply use $rootScope.tab = 1(tab number). It may be issue at your end.

Comment: I would recommend you to use $state.includes() instead of increasing code

Comment: Hello Mohan, I had put my example issue on plunker, would you be able to take a look? http://plnkr.co/edit/pkGgEFhG2FJNWT7xDfb4?p=preview  thank you

Comment: Ok , Let me have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update HTML :**

```
  <body ng-controller="NavCtrl">
    <!-- Desktop Menu -->
    <div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <a href="#/home" ng-class="{active: navTab === 1}" ng-click="navTab = 1">
            <li>Home</li>
          </a>
          <a href="#/qa" ng-class="{active: navTab === 2}" ng-click="navTab = 2">
            <li>QA</li>
          </a>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div class="row">
          <div ui-view="view50"></div>
          <div ui-view="view60"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

[Working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0GnJkFjfenKCtacjAQQH?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you Mohan for the respond, it help my fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your implementation and have no issues. Simply use the $rootScope variable directly in your template along side ng-class like so:

```
<body ng-controller="NavCtrl">
    <a ng-class="{red: $root.navTab===0}" ui-sref="first">first</a>
    <a ng-class="{red: $root.navTab===1}" ui-sref="second">second</a>
    <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

Then update $rootScope in your controllers.

```
.controller('NavCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {});

.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.navTab = 0;
});

.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.navTab = 1;
});
```

Your states get to stay relatively simple:

```
.state('first', {
    url: '/first',
    templateUrl:  'first.html',
    controller: 'FirstCtrl'
})
.state('second', {
    url: '/second',
    templateUrl:  'second.html',
    controller: 'SecondCtrl'
})
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/z82Ax5pGs2mcahW4uCSy?p=preview)

Ideally you would make a directive for such a task, and avoid using $rootScope. A simple way to do this is to broadcast a message whenever you land on a new page, then listen on that event in your tab directive and flip the correct tab as active.

Comment: Hello Soote, thank you for the respond, I was already able to have the active menu change when click on the menu, but the issue is if I have a link in the 2nd view that reference to 1st view, the active menu does not change from 2nd menu to 1st menu when I click    in 2nd view: <a href="#/first">go back to first</a> , after click on the link the view go to 1st view but the menu does not change from 2nd menu to 1st menu.  Thank you

Comment: Use ui-sref instead of href. My method works as expected with changing any code. Here's a plunker that changes the active state when a link on the page is clicked: http://plnkr.co/edit/GaG2C1BPxplLIGIAujvu?p=preview

Comment: Hello Soote, thank you for the comment, I had follow your example but still not able to get it working, would you be able to take a look at this plnker? http://plnkr.co/edit/pkGgEFhG2FJNWT7xDfb4?p=preview  Thank you

Comment: In your index.html file, you need to call $root.navTab in the ng-class, not navTab.